# Bloated UNION ALL code (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, union-all

I am a self-taught in SQL and I have some messy code that is dreadfully slow. I am visualizing this data in Tableau and the view I am creating became so slow that I had to create a table (refreshed daily) with all of the information I need.

I believe the slowness is due to the huge number of UNION ALL statements I am performing here. I'm doing this to "Pivot" the data so each question isn't it's own column in the DB, but rather an attribute of each row.

Can anyone provide some tips on how I could restructure the code to speed it up?
Any help or criticism would be appreciated, thanks! (Below is just a snippit of my code, the number of UNION ALL blocks continues....

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED 
DEFINER=root@localhost 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW view_data435386_xxxxx_MASTER AS


SELECT _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.ID AS ID,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.ID AS Comment_Photos_ID,
'Job Profile' AS Impact_Area,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.PARENT_RECORD_ID AS PARENT_RECORD_ID,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq1 AS PJQ1,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_2 AS PJQ2,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_3 AS PJQ3,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_4 AS PJQ4,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_5 AS PJQ5,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_6 AS PJQ6,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_7 AS PJQ7,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_8 AS PJQ8,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_9 AS PJQ9,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_10 AS PJQ10,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.additional_comments AS Additional_Comments,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.wr_,
NULL AS Completion_Due_Date,
NULL AS Completion_Due_Date_1443,
NULL AS Training_Needed,
NULL AS Follow_Up_Description,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.inspector, '_', ' ') AS Inspector,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.crew_leader, '_', ' ') AS Crew_Leader,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.date1 AS date1,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.district, '_', ' ') AS District,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division, '_', ' ') AS Division,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.contractor_inspected, '_', ' ') AS Contractor_Inspected,
301 Sample_Size_Req,
        (CASE
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                38197
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                3734
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                5044
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                55214
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                37742
            ELSE NULL   
        END) AS Population_size,
'1_Job Profile' AS Results,
3438545 AS Parent_Page_ID,
'1.0 Job Profile' AS Task,
'1.0 Job Profile' AS Construction_Activity,
NULL AS Overall_Rating,
CONCAT('https://xxxxx.xxxxx.com/exzact/dataPDF.php?TABLE_NAME=_data435386_xxxxx_main_form&ID=',
                `_data435386_xxxxx_main_form`.`ID`,
                '&PAGE_ID=3438731&USERNAME=xxxxx1&PASSWORD=xxxxx') AS `report_url`
FROM
(_data435386_xxxxx_main_form 
LEFT JOIN _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile ON((_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.ID = _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.PARENT_RECORD_ID)))
UNION ALL 


SELECT _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.ID AS ID,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.ID AS Comment_Photos_ID,
'Safety' AS Impact_Area,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.PARENT_RECORD_ID AS PARENT_RECORD_ID,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq1 AS PJQ1,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_2 AS PJQ2,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_3 AS PJQ3,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_4 AS PJQ4,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_5 AS PJQ5,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_6 AS PJQ6,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_7 AS PJQ7,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_8 AS PJQ8,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_9 AS PJQ9,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_10 AS PJQ10,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.additional_comments AS Additional_Comments,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.wr_,
NULL AS Completion_Due_Date,
NULL AS Completion_Due_Date_1443,
NULL AS Training_Needed,
NULL AS Follow_Up_Description,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.inspector, '_', ' ') AS Inspector,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.crew_leader, '_', ' ') AS Crew_Leader,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.date1 AS date1,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.district, '_', ' ') AS District,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division, '_', ' ') AS Division,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.contractor_inspected, '_', ' ') AS Contractor_Inspected,
301 Sample_Size_Req,
        (CASE
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                38197
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                3734
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                5044
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                55214
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                37742
            ELSE NULL   
        END) AS Population_size,
21_Uses_proper_ppe AS Results,
3438623 AS Parent_Page_ID,
'2.1 Uses Proper PPE' AS Task,
'2.0 Safety' AS Construction_Activity,
NULL AS Overall_Rating,
CONCAT('https://xxxxx.xxxxx.com/exzact/dataPDF.php?TABLE_NAME=_data435386_xxxxx_main_form&ID=',
                `_data435386_xxxxx_main_form`.`ID`,
                '&PAGE_ID=3438731&USERNAME=xxxxx1&PASSWORD=xxxxx') AS `report_url`
FROM
((_data435386_xxxxx_main_form 
LEFT JOIN view_data435386_xxxxx_2_task_successful ON((_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.ID = view_data435386_xxxxx_2_task_successful.PARENT_RECORD_ID))) 
LEFT JOIN _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile ON((_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.ID = _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.PARENT_RECORD_ID)))
WHERE 21_Uses_proper_ppe IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 





SELECT _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.ID AS ID,
view_data435386_xxxxx_2_task_successful.ID AS Comment_Photos_ID,
'Safety' AS Impact_Area,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.PARENT_RECORD_ID AS PARENT_RECORD_ID,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq1 AS PJQ1,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_2 AS PJQ2,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_3 AS PJQ3,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_4 AS PJQ4,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_5 AS PJQ5,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_6 AS PJQ6,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_7 AS PJQ7,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_8 AS PJQ8,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_9 AS PJQ9,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_10 AS PJQ10,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.additional_comments AS Additional_Comments,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.wr_,
NULL AS Completion_Due_Date,
NULL AS Completion_Due_Date_1443,
NULL AS Training_Needed,
NULL AS Follow_Up_Description,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.inspector, '_', ' ') AS Inspector,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.crew_leader, '_', ' ') AS Crew_Leader,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.date1 AS date1,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.district, '_', ' ') AS District,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division, '_', ' ') AS Division,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.contractor_inspected, '_', ' ') AS Contractor_Inspected,
301 Sample_Size_Req,
        (CASE
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                38197
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                3734
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                5044
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                55214
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                37742
            ELSE NULL   
        END) AS Population_size,
22_Damage_Prevention AS Results,
3438623 AS Parent_Page_ID,
'2.2 Damage Prevention' AS Task,
'2.0 Safety' AS Construction_Activity,
NULL AS Overall_Rating,
CONCAT('https://xxxxx.xxxxx.com/exzact/dataPDF.php?TABLE_NAME=_data435386_xxxxx_main_form&ID=',
                `_data435386_xxxxx_main_form`.`ID`,
                '&PAGE_ID=3438731&USERNAME=xxxxx1&PASSWORD=xxxxx') AS `report_url`
FROM
((_data435386_xxxxx_main_form 
LEFT JOIN view_data435386_xxxxx_2_task_successful ON((_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.ID = view_data435386_xxxxx_2_task_successful.PARENT_RECORD_ID))) 
LEFT JOIN _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile ON((_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.ID = _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.PARENT_RECORD_ID)))
WHERE 22_Damage_Prevention IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 





SELECT _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.ID AS ID,
view_data435386_xxxxx_2_task_successful.ID AS Comment_Photos_ID,
'Safety' AS Impact_Area,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.PARENT_RECORD_ID AS PARENT_RECORD_ID,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq1 AS PJQ1,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_2 AS PJQ2,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_3 AS PJQ3,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_4 AS PJQ4,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_5 AS PJQ5,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_6 AS PJQ6,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_7 AS PJQ7,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_8 AS PJQ8,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_9 AS PJQ9,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_10 AS PJQ10,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.additional_comments AS Additional_Comments,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.wr_,
NULL AS Completion_Due_Date,
NULL AS Completion_Due_Date_1443,
NULL AS Training_Needed,
NULL AS Follow_Up_Description,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.inspector, '_', ' ') AS Inspector,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.crew_leader, '_', ' ') AS Crew_Leader,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.date1 AS date1,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.district, '_', ' ') AS District,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division, '_', ' ') AS Division,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.contractor_inspected, '_', ' ') AS Contractor_Inspected,
301 Sample_Size_Req,
        (CASE
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                38197
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                3734
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                5044
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                55214
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                37742
            ELSE NULL   
        END) AS Population_size,
23_fire_bottle_and_no_smoking_sign AS Results,
3438623 AS Parent_Page_ID,
'2.3 Fire Bottle and No Smoking Sign' AS Task,
'2.0 Safety' AS Construction_Activity,
NULL AS Overall_Rating,
CONCAT('https://xxxxx.xxxxx.com/exzact/dataPDF.php?TABLE_NAME=_data435386_xxxxx_main_form&ID=',
                `_data435386_xxxxx_main_form`.`ID`,
                '&PAGE_ID=3438731&USERNAME=xxxxx1&PASSWORD=xxxxx') AS `report_url`
FROM
((_data435386_xxxxx_main_form 
LEFT JOIN view_data435386_xxxxx_2_task_successful ON((_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.ID = view_data435386_xxxxx_2_task_successful.PARENT_RECORD_ID))) 
LEFT JOIN _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile ON((_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.ID = _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.PARENT_RECORD_ID)))
WHERE 23_fire_bottle_and_no_smoking_sign IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL 





SELECT _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.ID AS ID,
view_data435386_xxxxx_2_task_successful.ID AS Comment_Photos_ID,
'Safety' AS Impact_Area,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.PARENT_RECORD_ID AS PARENT_RECORD_ID,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq1 AS PJQ1,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_2 AS PJQ2,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_3 AS PJQ3,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_4 AS PJQ4,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_5 AS PJQ5,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_6 AS PJQ6,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_7 AS PJQ7,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_8 AS PJQ8,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_9 AS PJQ9,
_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.pjq_10 AS PJQ10,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.additional_comments AS Additional_Comments,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.wr_,
NULL AS Completion_Due_Date,
NULL AS Completion_Due_Date_1443,
NULL AS Training_Needed,
NULL AS Follow_Up_Description,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.inspector, '_', ' ') AS Inspector,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.crew_leader, '_', ' ') AS Crew_Leader,
_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.date1 AS date1,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.district, '_', ' ') AS District,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division, '_', ' ') AS Division,
REPLACE(_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.contractor_inspected, '_', ' ') AS Contractor_Inspected,
NULL Sample_Size_Req,
        (CASE
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                38197
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                3734
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                5044
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                55214
            WHEN
                (_data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.division = 'xxxxx')
            THEN
                37742
            ELSE NULL   
        END) AS Population_size,
24_traffic_control_plan AS Results,
3438623 AS Parent_Page_ID,
'2.4 Traffic Control Plan' AS Task,
'2.0 Safety' AS Construction_Activity,
NULL AS Overall_Rating,
CONCAT('https://xxxxx.xxxxx.com/exzact/dataPDF.php?TABLE_NAME=_data435386_xxxxx_main_form&ID=',
                `_data435386_xxxxx_main_form`.`ID`,
                '&PAGE_ID=3438731&USERNAME=xxxxx1&PASSWORD=xxxxx') AS `report_url`
FROM
((_data435386_xxxxx_main_form 
LEFT JOIN view_data435386_xxxxx_2_task_successful ON((_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.ID = view_data435386_xxxxx_2_task_successful.PARENT_RECORD_ID))) 
LEFT JOIN _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile ON((_data435386_xxxxx_main_form.ID = _data435386_xxxxx_1_job_profile.PARENT_RECORD_ID)))
WHERE 24_traffic_control_plan IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
```

Comment: `UNION`s are generally not particularly performance intensive, as they are little more than appending one result set to another; you are better off looking into the performance of the queries being unioned.

Comment: Please highlight the difference(s) between the selects.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like several of the queries being UNIONed are nearly identical and serve only to produce multiple result rows with different `Results` and `Task` fields; you might want to look into merging those queries, or inserting a unified (with all values for `Results` fields as separate fields) version of the query into an intermediate (pseudo-temporary) table, and then UNIONing simpler queries against that.

*By "intermediate (pseudo-temporary)" I mean a non-temporary table you do not intend to keep; I would suggest a TEMPORARY table, but MySQL does not allow referencing more than once in the same query (such as UNIONs or self-JOINs).*

---

Edit: It's also not clear which table the `Result` values are coming from; if they are not from `_data435386_xxxxx_main_form` then you have some LEFT JOINs that can be INNER JOINs.